# Installing a printer without a ppd file

Tags: ubuntu, printing, ppd

I am trying to set up a computer linux to be able to print from my printer: Brother DCP 7030. But (twist!) for security reasons this computer should never go online. So any software I need to install will need to be downloaded with another machine, put in a usb stick, and copied onto the linux machine. Sweet.

The operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (not sure what does it mean).

OS type: 32-bit.

Now the system seem to only accept PPD files as printer drivers. While Brother does not offer any ppd file for this printer (I tried the 7025 and 7045, but they don't work).

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-7030

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried a generic Postscript PPD?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that does not work. When I try to print a test page it prints one page after the other of white pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to read [Brother instructions](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html) to install the drivers on Ubuntu

**First**
you will need to have `ia32-libs` or `lib32stdc++` installed.

**Second**
Download the `deb` package for your printer

**Third**
install the printer driver `deb` package with the command :

```
dpkg -i nameofpackage.deb  
#the web site mention the use of --force-all but I do not recommand it 
#(use only if standard way does not work
```

**Fourth**
I really don't understand the instructino bt it mention the modification of the file `/etc/printcap` accroding to your config, but as I will not install that driver I can't help you uch further.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I might have installed it, but I am lost at step 5 (what you call step 4). When I do more printecap it says this file was automatically generated by cupsd(8). So CUPS is installed??

Comment: Well it's very likely the case

Comment: Yes, ok. I had to reinstall it using CUPS (whatever that is). Then take away the proxy from firefox. Then checked the localhost. And now it works. Simple. ;-). Thank you very much, I saw those instructions before but could not understand them the first time.

Comment: Ok glad this help you.

Comment: `dpkg` package? `deb` package.

Comment: @enedil `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` ?

Comment: I mean the name. `dpkg` package is there: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dpkg

Comment: OK I really didn't get what you were sayng, I think it's better now.